# sorting an array of pointers according to the integers value

Tags: c

I got this as homework. using merge-sort, I'm trying to sort an array of integers that a new array of pointers will hold the pointers to each integer in the right order
so if arr = {7,2,5,9,4} than the pointers array will be {ptr to 2, ptr to 4, ptr to 5, ptr to 7, ptr to 9}

so, at first I was required to write the function as following:

```
int** pointerSort(int* arr, int size);
```

and I did that:

```
int** pointerSort(int* arr, int size) {
int **res1, **res2, **res;
if (size <= 1) {
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;

    res = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    *res = arr;

    return res;
}

res1 = pointerSort(arr, size/2);
res2 = pointerSort(arr + size/2, size - size/2);

res = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int **) * size);
merge(res1,size/2,res2, size - size/2,res);

return res;
}


void merge (int **arr1, int size1, int **arr2, int size2, int **res) {

int i1,i2, resI;
i1 = i2 = resI = 0;

while (i1 < size1 && i2 < size2) {
    if (**(arr1 + i1) <= **(arr2 + i2)){
        *(res + resI++) = *(arr1 + i1++);
    }
    else {
        *(res + resI++) = *(arr2 + i2++);
    }
}
while (i1 < size1) {
    *(res + resI++) = *(arr1 + i1++);
}

while (i2 < size2) {
    *(res + resI++) = *(arr2 + i2++);
}
}
```

but after that I needed to change it to

```
void pointerSort2(int* arr, int size, int*** pointers);
```

and that's where I'm stuck.
This is what I've got so far and it doesn't seem to work

```
void pointerSort2(int* arr, int size, int*** pointers) {
    if (size <= 1) {
        if (size == 0)
            return;

        pointers = (int ***)malloc(size * sizeof(int ***));
        *pointers = &arr;

        return;
    }
    pointerSort2(arr, size/2,pointers);
    pointerSort2(arr + size/2, size - size/2,pointers);

    int ***res = (int ***)malloc(sizeof(int ***) * size);
    merge2(pointers,size/2,pointers, size - size/2,res);

    pointers = res;
}

void merge2 (int ***arr1, int size1, int ***arr2, int size2, int ***res) {
    int i1,i2, resI;
    i1 = i2 = resI = 0;
    int val;
    int val2;
    int b;
    while (i1 < size1 && i2 < size2) {
            int val = ***(arr1 + i1);
    int val2 = ***(arr2 + i2);
    int b = ***(arr1 + i1) <= ***(arr2 + i2);
        if (b) {
            *(res + resI++) = *(arr1 + i1++);
        }
        else {
            *(res + resI++) = *(arr2 + i2++);
        }
    }
    while (i1 < size1) {
        *(res + resI++) = *(arr1 + i1++);
    }

    while (i2 < size2) {
        *(res + resI++) = *(arr2 + i2++);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: There is no question here. "*after that I needed to change it to*" and "*that's where I'm stuck*" do not form anything comprehensible. Clearly **state the requirements** and **how** did you try to fulfill them and **what** went wrong.

Comment: From a brief look you have allocation mistakes in both of your versions. `malloc` works this way: `Type* res = malloc(sizeof(Type) * size);` - mind the correctness of dereferences.

Comment: Do some work on this code, and then put only the doubtful code where you may find some problem. To put all the code is not right way to ask the question. So, for quick and better solution, put your actual problem rather then whole code. Please refer it [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: icepack3, there is a question here - the requirements were that I take pointerSort function and change it's signature so that int ***pointers holds what pointerSort returned originally. and While doing that I got stuck - and the code is below

Comment: Yes Armen, I tried to debug it... unfortunately I can't put my finger on the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I have 2 remarks for you concerning the first function `pointerSort()`

1) replace the allocation of res

```
res = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
res = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int**) * size);
```

with only

```
res = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * size);
```

2) add `free` for `res1` and `res2` after the merge otherwise you will get a memory leak

```
res = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int **) * size);
merge(res1,size/2,res2, size - size/2,res);
free(res1);
free(res2);
```

Concerning your functions `pointerSort2` and `merge2` : there is many code errors in both function. here after the new code fixed.

Note: Playing with multi level pointer is some thing complicated. be careful when use it

```
void pointerSort2(int* arr, int size, int*** pointers) {
    int **tmp;
    int **pointers1, **pointers2;
    if (size <= 1) {
        if (size == 0)
            return;

        tmp = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int **));
        *tmp = arr;
        *pointers = tmp;
        return;
    }
    pointerSort2(arr, size/2,&pointers1);
    pointerSort2(arr + size/2, size - size/2,&pointers2);


    merge2(pointers1,size/2,pointers2, size - size/2,&tmp);
    free(pointers1);
    free(pointers2);    
    *pointers = tmp;
}

void merge2 (int **arr1, int size1, int **arr2, int size2, int ***res) {
    int i1,i2, resI;
    i1 = i2 = resI = 0;
    int val;
    int val2;
    int b;
    int **tmp = (int **)malloc((size1+size2) * sizeof(int **));
    *res = tmp;
    while (i1 < size1 && i2 < size2) {
            int val = **(arr1 + i1);
    int val2 = **(arr2 + i2);
    int b = **(arr1 + i1) <= **(arr2 + i2);
        if (b) {
            *(tmp + resI++) = *(arr1 + i1++);
        }
        else {
            *(tmp + resI++) = *(arr2 + i2++);
        }
    }
    while (i1 < size1) {
        *(tmp + resI++) = *(arr1 + i1++);
    }

    while (i2 < size2) {
        *(tmp + resI++) = *(arr2 + i2++);
    }
}
```

The call of `pointerSort2` in the `main` should be

```
int arr[5] = {2, 5, 3, 7, 6}
int **res;
pointerSort2(arr, 5, &res);
```

Comment: @TomerGal Answer updated. it contains the code fixed of both function pointerSort2 and merge2